# ListView свободная прокрутка.

Tags: android, listview, java

С помощью `ListView.setStackFromBottom(true);` я установил автоматическую прокрутку при обновлении `ListView` к последнему пункту.

**Вопрос.** каким образом вернуть свободную прокрутку? :D

`ListView.setStackFromBottom(false)` - не канает(скрулит автоматом к первому символу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очистить список, установить `ListView.setStackFromBottom(false)` и заполнить заново -это конечно радикально.

Можно попробовать еще вариант перевертывания getItem() - то есть выдавать элементы в перевернутом виде.